# how to validate user input in an array

Tags: powershell

I have this simple code that I'm experimenting with and learning about arrays.

```
$InputArray = @(1,2,3)
$UserInput = Read-Host 'Choose your template code'
if ($UserInput -in $InputArray) {
    'valid'
} else {
    'not valid'
}
```

This script above is understandable and is working but then I tried something like this:

```
$InputArray = @(Get-SPWebTemplate | Select-Object Name)
$UserInput = Read-Host 'Choose your template code'
if ($UserInput -in $InputArray) {
    'valid'
} else {
    'not valid'
}
```

but it didn't work, so basically the `Get-SPWebTemplate | Select-Object Name`
gives us a list of templates and I tried to store them within the `$InputArray` array and then check the input if it is included in the array or not. But the result is always 'not valid' even if the userinput was actually 'valid' or in the array.

Why isn't it working and how can this be better to make it work?

Comment: `Select-Object Name` -> `Select-Object -Expand Name`. Currently you're comparing a string to a list of custom objects with a property `Name` when you actually want to compare it to a list of strings.

Comment: That did it :), thank you for explaining too